# Saml authentication Spring Security Core (since 5.2) in xml configuration

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-security-saml2

We are currently using xml configuration as described [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/current/reference/html/). This depends on opensaml.
Since Spring security 5.2, SAML authentication is integrated in spring security core as announced [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#saml2login-spring-security-saml2-history).

I did find an example of configuring this [via @nnotations](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/18260).

Does anyone have a reference to an example of configuring Spring Security SAML authentication 'the new spring core 5.2 way' in XML configuration *(so without the OpenSAML dependency)*?

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you already found some examples?

Comment: I'm afraid not. I'm sorry

Comment: I'm looking for it also. Still do not know how to call http.saml2Login(withDefaults()) in XML configuration